# I need to write a subscribe to the cmd_vel for turtlebot

Tags: ros, navigation, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to write a subscribe to the cmd_vel topic, where am publishing to turtlebot the gazebo. So I want to return the speed turtlebot through the subscriber, not chei code examples for this case, I'm using an example of publisher where the directional control turtlebot in the gazebo. would be grateful for any help! !

I know I have 2 variables that the publisher would velocidada the angular and linear speed, but I need a topic that returns me the speed if not possible at least the subscriber's cmd_vel help me.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196933/i-need-to-write-a-subscribe-to-the-cmd_vel-for-turtlebot/) by [leobber](https://answers.ros.org/users/20424/leobber/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-11-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [leobber](https://answers.ros.org/users/20424/leobber/) on 2014-11-07**:
Você diz publicar e subscrever do nó odom ? funciona mesmo com o turtlebot simulation ?

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-11-07**:
Yes it works even with turtlebot.
/odom gives you the current speed and current position of your robot. But I advise you...you didn't tell too much about your project

**Comment by [leobber](https://answers.ros.org/users/20424/leobber/) on 2014-11-07**:
So that's exactly what I need, first I want to publish turtlebot speed, ie move it around the map, but I'm doing it for cmd_vel topic and noticed that just do to set values for position update,

**Comment by [leobber](https://answers.ros.org/users/20424/leobber/) on 2014-11-07**:
Which is the precise speed real robot just need a publisher and a simple subscribe so I can publish and move the turtle and have it return the actual speed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

using `/odom` you get the information you need.
It publishes actual position and velocity informations of your robot.

`/cmd_vel` takes just the desired velocity and moves your robot accordingly.
Usually one publishes on `/cmd_vel` to move the robot and subscribes on `/odom` to get the wanted informations.

I can strongly suggest to buy the following [book](http://www.lulu.com/shop/r-patrick-goebel/ros-by-example-hydro-volume-1/ebook/product-21393108.html) because it has a very good any clear example on what you are going to do.

---

Originally posted by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) with karma: 893 on 2014-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [leobber](https://answers.ros.org/users/20424/leobber/) on 2014-11-08**:
Oh how wonderful is exactly what I need, my difficulty now would be like this I do know well the publisher subscriber but do not yet have examples of subscriber!

**Comment by [leobber](https://answers.ros.org/users/20424/leobber/) on 2014-11-08**:
Muito o bom o livro pena que tava querendo esse subscriber logo : /////, e sou do brasil não achei o livro nas livrarias daqui. Oh god vou procurar no forum ver se acho um exemplo de subscriber simples para o /odom. Muito obrigado

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-11-08**:
You can buy the book online as PDF file. It is not expensive
Muito obrigado para mim, but click on the small green check symbol to post the answer as given